# Can't convert NSString to NSDate object

Tags: iphone, ios

This is an example result to string from my server:

> Sat, 24 Dec 2011 14:33:43 +0000

I'm trying to convert it to NSDate and I keep getting null.

This is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

Why do I get null?

Comment: have you checked what string you would get using `[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]`?

Comment: Are you sure that "Sat, 24 Dec 2011 14:33:43 +0000" is exactly what you're getting from the server? If it is even a little bit different, dateFromString: will return NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine here.  You probably want your format to be this tho:

```
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
```

Otherwise it'll fail if the server returns a timezone that's not GMT.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSString *dateString =@"Sat, 24 Dec 2011 14:33:43 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else must be wrong with your code. Check where you allocate or assign dateString. That might be null to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code with the string you said you're getting from the server and it's working fine. I even tried what mvds said about using `[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]` that's also returning the correct date